# Player Direction looks right when going left player looks back when going forward

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, controller, blender

I'm
Making a third person controller based off of this tutorial
https://youtu.be/suU4aBdBjKA
One problem is. My character will go left, but face right.
If I go forward my character faces back instead of the way it's going.
I tried rotating the character but that did not do the job, as the character snaps back in place.
Though that is not the problem.
The only problem is, is that the character does not face where it's going.

I tried rotating the character but that did not do a thing. This is only when the character is moving. It looks the opposite way that it is moving towards.

I tried putting a plus under the handle rotation "="
but that did not do a thing, as I was looking for the comments inside of the video and have found nothing.

Here's the codes. Is there something I can fix?

Here's the PLAYER LOCAL MOTION
`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerLocomotion : MonoBehaviour
{
    InputManager inputManager;

    Vector3 moveDirection;
    Transform cameraObject;
    Rigidbody playerRigidBody;

    public float movementSpeed = 7;
    public float rotationSpeed = 15;

    private void Awake()
    {
        inputManager = GetComponent<InputManager>();
        playerRigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        cameraObject = Camera.main.transform;
    }
    public void HandleAllMovement()
    {
        HandleMovement();
        HandleRotation();

    }
    private void HandleMovement()
    {
        moveDirection = cameraObject.forward * inputManager.verticalInput;
        moveDirection = moveDirection + cameraObject.right * inputManager.horizontalInput;
        moveDirection.Normalize();
        moveDirection.y = 0; 
        moveDirection = moveDirection * movementSpeed;
        
        Vector3 movementVelocity = moveDirection; 
        playerRigidBody.velocity = movementVelocity;
    }

    private void HandleRotation()
    {
        Vector3 targetDirection = Vector3.zero;

        targetDirection = cameraObject.forward * inputManager.verticalInput;
        targetDirection = targetDirection + cameraObject.right * inputManager.horizontalInput;
        targetDirection.Normalize();
        targetDirection.y = 0;

        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetDirection);
        Quaternion playerRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        
        transform.rotation = playerRotation;
    }
}
```

`

Here's the PLAYER MANAGER
`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    InputManager inputManager;
    PlayerLocomotion playerLocomotion;
   private void Awake()
   {
    inputManager = GetComponent<InputManager>();
    playerLocomotion = GetComponent<PlayerLocomotion>();


   }
   private void Update()
   {
       inputManager.HandleAllInputs();
   }

   private void FixedUpdate()
   {
       playerLocomotion.HandleAllMovement();
   }
}
```

`Here's the INPUT MANAGER`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InputManager : MonoBehaviour
{
 PlayerControls playerControls;

 public Vector2 movementInput; 
 public float verticalInput;
 public float horizontalInput;
 

 private void OnEnable()
 {
    if (playerControls == null)
    {
        playerControls = new PlayerControls();

        playerControls.PlayerMovement.Movement.performed += i => movementInput = i.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        
    }
    playerControls.Enable();

 }

 private void OnDisable()
 {
    playerControls.Disable();
 }
 public void HandleAllInputs()
 {
   HandleMovementInput();
   //HandleJumpingInput
   //HandleActionInput
 }
 private void HandleMovementInput()
 {
   verticalInput = movementInput.y;
   horizontalInput = movementInput.x;
 }
}
```

`

They are all connected together. I just can't get the feeling or understanding of whats's wrong with it that could be causing the player to move this way.

Any help is apprietiated. This is Unity.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try inverting the input in the rotation function.

```
targetDirection = cameraObject.forward * -inputManager.verticalInput;
targetDirection = targetDirection + cameraObject.right * -inputManager.horizontalInput;
```